# как сделать запрос к своему серверу ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Делаю запрос к своему серверу через библиотеку `axios` но получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в чем может быть проблема и как решить эту задачу?

[полный код](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-j5u1r6?embed=1&file=src/common/home/homerecommend.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых где вы видели такой код?

```
async componentDidMount(){}
```

Какой еще `async` перед `componentDidMount`.

`componentDidMount` вызывается  лишь раз во всем жизненном цикле компонента и  сигнализирует, что компонент и все его дочерние компоненты отрисовались без ошибок.Никаких `async` и `await` не надо добавлять перед ним.

Во вторых вы подключили `axios` а используете `fetch`

```
 async componentDidMount(){
    fetch("http://yunuso2c.beget.tech/?route=extension/aliexpress/home/homerecommend")
```

Запомните `axios` (и другие npm пакеты **SuperAgent**, **Request** для того чтобы выполнять запросы на сервер) упрощенная альтернатива `fetch`.Используйте либо первый либо второй но не оба сразу.

В третьих даже если код будет правильным запросы к вашему серверу будут неудачными.

Исправленная персия вашего кода.

```
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('http://yunuso2c.beget.tech/?route=extension/aliexpress/home/homerecommend')
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

Если заменить этот код на ваш все равно не сработает потому что проблема у вас на сервере.Вставьте вместо вашего сервера адрес `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` и посмотрите в консоль и увидите что все данные на месте все работает корректно.Дата выводится.

Comment: Я прочитал пару ответов на `stackoverflow` тут сказано что на сервере нужно настроить cors, откуда вы узнали что проблема у меня ещё на сервере?

Comment: @newProgrammer так потому что там и кода та нету чтобы ошибку ловить в коде .Это стандартный запрос к серверу либо он отвечает либо он настроен не правильно.